# adding 1 day to date and time

Tags: php, date, time

I need to add 1 day to my date and here is my code:

```
<?php
$starttime="2015-05-14 13:24";
$date=date_create($starttime);
date_modify($date,"+1 day");
$date=date_format($date,"Y-m-d h:m:s");
echo $date;
?>
```

When I run it should give me "2015-05-15 13:24", but it gives me "2015-05-15 01:05:00".

Why does it change hour and minute?

Comment: Change `"Y-m-d h:m:s"` to `"Y-m-d h:i:s"`, because format character `m` is month, not minutes.

Comment: WOW, damn it, i was never thinking about it haha thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+1 days');
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Or for 24hr clock:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d G:i:s');
```

`m` is used to format month

`i` is used to format hour in the way that you want

Comment: thanks, and what should i do to show hour in 24h format?